# Heroku: Django Migration release not running in deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-migrations

I have a Django application running in Heroku.  On the initial deployment, I manually migrated the database schema using `heroku run`.

The next time I needed to push migrations to the app, the release went off without a complaint.
However, when I went to the page to see it live, I was returned a programming error: the new column didn't exist. The migrations had never been run.

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn APP_NAME.wsgi --log-file -
release: python manage.py migrate
release: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
worker: celery worker -A APP_NAME -B -E -l info
```

The collectstatic release is run successfully, but the migrate release is seemingly ignored or overlooked.  When I manually migrated, they migrated without error.  There *is* an empty `__init__.py` file in the migrations folder.

If anyone knows what could possibly be hindering the migrate release from running, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I've figured it out.  Although in its documentation Heroku seems to imply that there can be more than one release tag in a Procfile, this is untrue.

The last `release` tag in the Procfile takes precedent.
This means that in order to run multiple commands in the release stage, you have to use a shell script.

Now, my Procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn APP_NAME.wsgi --log-file -
release: ./release.sh
worker: celery worker -A APP_NAME -B -E -l info
```

And I have a `release.sh` script that looks like this:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

**MAKE SURE TO MAKE YOUR `RELEASE.SH` SCRIPT EXECUTABLE:**

Running `chmod u+x release.sh` in terminal prior to committing should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment @rchurch4's answer, here it is: if you just have a few commands to run at release time, you can use the following in your Procfile:

```
release:  command1 && command2 && command3 [etc.]
```

for instance

```
release:  python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata foo && python manage.py your_custom_management_command
```